# Computing gcd without modular arithmetic

Tags: number-theory

What will make the following specification complete?

$gcd(x,y) = gcd((x-y)/2,y)$ when $x,y$ are odd

$gcd(x,y) = gcd(x/2,y)$ when $x$ is even and $y$ is odd

$gcd(x,y) = gcd(x,y/2)$ when $x$ is odd and $y$ is even

Will the $gcd(x,y) = gcd(x/2,y/2)$ when $x$ and $y$ are both even? How do I know what value to "return" as the gcd of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Consider $x=2^AC,y=2^BD$ where $C,D$ are odd and  integer $A,B\ge0$

Comment: Questions like “Will the $\gcd(x,y)=\gcd(x/2,y/2)$ when $x$ and $y$ are both even?”can be easily answered  by considering a couple of examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course $\gcd(x,y)=2\cdot\gcd(\frac x2,\frac y2)$ if $x,y$ are both even!Note that once you have extracted the maximum possible power of $2$ with this last rule, you can continue only with your other three rules until one of $x,y$ becomes $1$.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little? What conditions needs to hold for this equation to be true? When will it give us the gcd for any two numbers x and y?

Comment: What do you mean by "maximum possible power of 2?"